# Python + OpenCV - Saving an image to a specific directory

Tags: python, image, opencv, save

I have the following script where I'm trying to read and image and save (write) it to a directory. The script runs without any errors, but I cannot find the image being written to that directory, why is that?

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
path = '/home/user/Desktop/my_folder/'
cv2.imwrite(str(path) + str(img) + '.jpg', img)
```

Thanks.

Comment: What does `print(str(img))` print out? Is it a valid filename?

Comment: Did the `imread` succeed? It's not obvious as you don't test it. Does `imwrite` succeed? Again you don't test the return value. Does it create a file if you exclude the path?

Comment: @LeopoldVonBuschLight Oh, right, completely missed that attempt to make a filename by stringizing the image. Good catch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right way to combine paths is with `os.path.join`:

```
import os
cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(path, 'your_image.jpg'), img)
```

Also, ensure that `str(img)` is a valid name for a file, otherwise, use something else.